# multiple owners to a `tokio_tungstenite` wss stream

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. I want to obtain read/write WebSocket streams and send sth to a server to start receiving data.
2. Run an indefinite background loop, reading responses and writing back when certain responses are received. The loop must be non-blocking.
3. Use the same wss `write` stream to send other data based on signals from my main program.

I am facing two problems:

- First, I cannot run the loop asynchronously without having to move both the `read` and `write` into `tokio::spawn`, thus losing ownership, and step 3 is never achieved.
- Second, the `tokio::spawn` is never executed if I don't await it.

pseudocode below for reference.

```
let (stream, _) = tokio_tungstenite::connect_async(<url>).await.unwrap();
let (mut write, read) = stream.split();

// 1. write sth to server
write.send(<sth>).await.unwrap();

// 2. run indefinitely 
tokio::spawn(
    loop {
        match read.next().await {
               "ping" => write.send("pong").await.unwrap(),
                ....
               "error" => break,
        }
     }
);

// 3. write more things to the same stream
write.send(<sth-else>).await.unwrap();
```

Comment: Tokio spawn blocks must have ownership of their members, so if you need to use `write` inside the spawn block and outside of it, you will probably need to use something like Arc on `write`. `use std::sync::Arc;`. And/or you may need RwLock (tokio::sync::RwLock) since it is mutable. Hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few months back its how I did it.
as it's mentioned in the comments you need to use ARC and an mpsc channel (like: [tokio mpsc](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/mpsc/struct.Sender.html))

here is how I've done it

```
// in the ws.rs file
    pub struct WsConnection {
    sender: flume::Sender<ws::Request>,
    resv: flume::Receiver<ws::Request>,
        }
impl WsConnection {
    pub async fn new() -> Arc<Self> {
        let (tx, rx) = flume::unbounded::<ws::Request>();
        Arc::new(Self {
            sender: tx,
            resv: rx,
        })
    }
    pub async fn connect_to_server<T, F>(self: &Arc<Self>, callback: T) -> Result<()>
    where
        T: Fn(Option<Payload>) -> F + Send + Sync + 'static,
        F: Future<Output = ()> + Send + 'static,
    {
        let case_url =
            Url::parse("YOUR URL");

        let (ws_stream, _) = connect_async(case_url).await?;

        let (mut user_ws_tx, mut user_ws_rx) = ws_stream.split();

        let resv = self.resv.clone();
        tokio::task::spawn(async move {
            while let Ok(message) = resv.recv_async().await {
                user_ws_tx
                    .send(/* try to send the message you received to sever*/)
                    .unwrap_or_else(|e| {
                        error!("websocket send error: {}", e);
                    })
                    .await;
            }
        });

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            while let Some(result) = user_ws_rx.next().await {
                // call the callback for handing the incoming request
                tokio::spawn(callback(msg));
            }
        });
        Ok(())
    }

    pub async fn send_msg(&self, msg: ws::Request) -> Result<()> {
        self.sender.send_async(msg).await?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

note that *ws::Request* is an enum for the incoming and outgoing requests type, yours can be anything you need. I'm using [flume](https://docs.rs/flume/latest/flume/) here but tokio mpsc should be fine too.

and when you want to use it , do it like this

```
 let ws = WsConnection::new().await;
   ws.connect_to_server(move |payload| {
        async move {
           //Handle the incoming request   
          // payload is the incoming request
        }
    })
    .await?;
```

and for sending a new request to the server use

```
ws.send_msg(/*your outgoing request*/)
```

and since ws is an ARC you can clone it anywhere you want